# why Angular services are not working inside the setTimeout and setInterval?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**create-to-do.component.html**

```
<p>create-to-do works!</p>
<form #todoForm="ngForm">
    <input type="text" name="task_name" palceholder="Task Name" [(ngModel)]="todo_service.selected_todo.name">
    <input type="text" name="description" palceholder="describe" [(ngModel)]="todo_service.selected_todo.description">
    
</form>
```

**create-to-do.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms'
import {TodoService} from '../shared/todo.service';
import {Todo} from '../shared/todo';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-to-do',
  templateUrl: './create-to-do.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-to-do.component.css'],
  providers:[TodoService]
})
export class CreateToDoComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public todo_service : TodoService) { }
  
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(' in ngOnInit function ');
    // yaha pr hm condition check krnge using set interval
    this.todo_service.selected_todo={
      name : "",
      description : ""
    };

   
   console.log(this.todo_service.selected_todo)
     let timerId  = setInterval(function(){
       console.log(this.todo_service.selected_todo);
       if(this.todo_service.selected_todo.name!="" && this.todo_service.selected_todo.description!=""){
         console.log(this.todo_service.selected_todo);
         clearTimeout(timerId);
       }
     },100);
  }

}
```

**shared\todo.ts**

```
export class Todo {

    name : String;
    description : String;
    
}
```

**shared\todo.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import  {Todo} from './todo';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TodoService {
   
  selected_todo : Todo;
  todos : Todo[]=[];

  constructor() { }
}
```

actually I want to run some functions when the form fields are completed filled, without any submit button and for that, I am using setInterval so that it can check my `todo_service.selected_todo` fields and if all the fields are not equal to an empty string then I will perform some operation, but inside the `setInterval`, I am getting error as `Cannot read property 'selected_todo' of undefined`.
and being fairly new to web dev, I am not able to identify why this error is coming.

Comment: Use arrow function instead of function expression  setInterval(()=> ... , so that it will bind to current class contex

Answer (score 0):

Try this to understand the problem:

```
let self = this;
let timerId  = setInterval(function(){
       console.log(self.todo_service.selected_todo);
       if(self.todo_service.selected_todo.name!="" && self.todo_service.selected_todo.description!=""){
         console.log(self.todo_service.selected_todo);
         clearTimeout(timerId);
       }
     },100);
```

Or this to solve it in a more elegant way:

```
let timerId  = setInterval(() => {
       console.log(this.todo_service.selected_todo);
       if(this.todo_service.selected_todo.name!="" && this.todo_service.selected_todo.description!=""){
         console.log(this.todo_service.selected_todo);
         clearTimeout(timerId);
       }
     },100);
```

Check the documentation here for more information as to why `this` is not referring to your class instance when accessed inside the `setInterval` function and any other function that is invoked as a callback: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_an_object_method

> A function's this keyword behaves a little differently in JavaScript compared to other languages. It also has some differences between strict mode and non-strict mode.
>
> In most cases, the value of this is determined by how a function is called (runtime binding). It can't be set by assignment during execution, and it may be different each time the function is called. ES5 introduced the bind() method to set the value of a function's this regardless of how it's called